# helm-M-x fuzzy not working (only match if provide proper prefix)

Tags: helm, helm-sources, m-x

I set helm-M-x-fuzzy-match to true, but it is not working as I want.
[image]

For example, if I type `log`:
[image]

I expect it to show `clm/toggle-command-log-buffer` as well.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Check out https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/13100.

There was a breaking change in Helm which removed the `fuzzy-` variables you defined.

In place, you have to set the following variables in your init.el:

For emacs27:

```
(setq helm-completion-style 'emacs)
(setq completion-styles '(flex))
```

For emacs26:

```
(setq helm-completion-style 'emacs)
(setq completion-styles '(helm-flex))
```

Hope that helps anyone else with the same issue.